Drawing Lagrange top in tikz
I would like to draw a Lagrange top in tikz, along the lines of the following image (taken from Thornton and Marion's "Classical Dynamics").

I have seen similar (simpler) drawings, but since I am totally new to tikz I am having a lot of problems drawing the shape of the top and the arcs illustrating the angles $\theta$ and $\psi$. Could anybody help with this? Thanks in advance!

Code along the lines of the image? This will look awesome!
Joke aside, this site is not meant to be a human-powered image-to-TikZ conversion tool. So, please help us help you and show some code that shows what you tried so far. It might be sufficient to only have the straight lines of the diagram first, but please do show some effort from your side. It should be reasonably simple to come up with some starting point. Also, how precise do you want the curves be? Do you have some reference link? TikZ has a nice online manual with tutorials.

Some hints. // I suggest doing the drawing in 2D, i.e. resist the temptation to use the 3D libs. // Look for \draw, \draw[dashed]. Look for entering points in polar notation, e.g. (1,1) is equivalent to (45:1.41) // For the greek arcs, look for the angles-tikzlibrary. // For placinng text look for \node and its anchors. E.g. axis x1 can be sth. like \draw (0,0) -- node[anchor=west]{$x_1$} (-30:2) . // Understand the path concept, which starts with \, ends with ; AND can do many actions in between, like draw and node (note the missing \ inside ...)

(I don't even understand the diagram you show. This is supposed to be 3-dimensional, right? But which are the three axis for the dimensions? x₁', x₂' and x₃'?)

@JasperHabicht Physics stuff: it's about rotated coordinate systems. E.g. to describe the motion of a gyro, it's helpful to align one axis (here x3) with its axis of rotation.

@MS-SPO Right, I just wondered, because if the angle arcs should be translated/transformed according to the dimensions, it would be necessary to know in which plane they lie.

@JasperHabicht It changes. The primed axes are the ordinary 3D ones, while the non-primed are moving in time (and space) with the tumbling gyro. As a simple case assume theta=const, psi==0, and phi(t) being linear in t: it rotates around x3-prime.

You could try something like this: (Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726815/319072)
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[below left]{$x_1^\prime$};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bx}{5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\by}{0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bz}{0}
    
    \draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[below right]{$x_2^\prime$};
    \draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[above]{$x_3^\prime$};

    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{130}{-30}{-70}
    \tdplottransformrotmain{5}{0}{0}
        \draw (0,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) node[below right]{$x_1$};
        \draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{\tdplotresx}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{\tdplotresy}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\az}{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cx}{\tdplotresx}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cy}{\tdplotresy}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cz}{\tdplotresz}
    \tdplottransformrotmain{0}{5}{0}
        \draw (0,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) node[below right]{$x_2$};
    \tdplottransformrotmain{0}{0}{5}
        \draw (0,0) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) node[above]{$x_3$};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\tdplotresx}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{\tdplotresy}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dz}{\tdplotresz}

    \foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,3}{
        \draw[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360,tdplot_rotated_coords]
        plot({sqrt(\y)*cos(\t)},{sqrt(\y)*sin(\t)},\y);
    }
    \foreach \t in {0,10,...,360}{
        \draw[smooth,variable=\y,domain=0:3,tdplot_rotated_coords] 
        plot ({sqrt(\y)*cos(\t)},{sqrt(\y)*sin(\t)},{\y}) -- (0,0,3);
    }

    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(\ax,\ay,\az)(\bx,\by,\bz)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,->]{4}{anchor=north}{$\theta$}

    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(\ax,\ay,\az)(\cx,\cy,\cz)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,->]{4}{anchor=west}{$\phi$}

    \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0,0,5)(\dx,\dy,\dz)
    \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,->]{4.5}{anchor=south}{$\phi$}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks a lot, @JasperHabicht! Although your solution comes close to what I need, I think that the original figure is using the ZXZ convention for the Euler angles (\phi,\theta,\psi), while you seem to use tikz's standard ZYZ convention. Also, I don't need the mesh in the rigid body, just a shading in the lateral surface. I don't know how to do this with tikz. I also need to draw a vector with origin on the x_3 axis but pointing along the x_3' axis, which I don't know how to do. I modified your solution as best as I could, but is not satisfactory. Perhaps I'll post a follow-up question.

@user3476591 I do not know how to use ZXZ angles in tikz, or if that is even readily possible out-of-the-box. I also do now know how to shade the surface. Maybe you could ask about those in separate questions. For the vector you mentioned, the axes are drawn in the main coordinate frame, so it should be as simple as taking a point along the axis, and then adding a line going straight down (with ++). The code is pretty complicated, so I can appreciate having trouble understanding it all initially, but try to look into how \tdplottransformrotmain is defined.
